# JSON Data is not returning as a string in swift

Tags: ios, json, xcode, string, swift

I am trying to return data from JSON object as a string but whenever I try it returns nil if someone could help please find the below code. I need to return currentWeather as a String with its value currently I am not able to return the data as a string only as an optional.

```
    let urlPath = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&units=metric"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        println("Task completed")
        if((error) != nil) {
            // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        var err: NSError?
        var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary


          let jsonDictionary = jsonResult as NSDictionary
            let mainDictionary = jsonResult.valueForKey("main") as NSDictionary
            let currentWeather = mainDictionary.valueForKey("humidity") as? NSString
        println(currentWeather)



    })
    task.resume()
```

Comment: Are you able to get "jsonResult" in above code? If yes, can you put log on jsonResult and share?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code. The 'humidity' is an Int, not String. So you should use

```
let currentWeather = mainDictionary.valueForKey("humidity") as Int
```